# Network Request with CFNetwork

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, network-programming, cfnetwork

**I try to write a HTTPRequester using CFNetwork and with Stream Reader.** It is just an a interface to send GET/POST/PUT... request but I can able to create the CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest and set header and postbody also create NSInputStream and successfully open it but the response callback is not getting fired.

Any idea?

I found the ASIHttp code but I cannot able to use it.
can any one give us a complete example code?

My end requirement is to work with socket. setting NTLM based authenticated GET/POST request through CFSocket. any help?

Can anyone give me a simple example about how to send a POST request using CFNetwork?

thanks in advance,

Naveen Shan